# Android Firebase OTP auth: Is there a way to cancel OTP code request programatically before the actual timeout?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

According to the [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone), a user cannot request a second OTP SMS if the first request hasn't timed out yet.

I want to cancel an ongoing OTP code request if.... let's say user navigate out from the Activity or Fragment where they request the OTP.

The current situation is that if a user back out from the OTP page  after they requested the SMS and they entered the page again, they cannot request the OTP until the request made before they back out from the page is timed out.

Here's the current callback I created:

```
mCallbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {

            executeTaskWhenVerificationSucceed()
        }


        override fun onVerificationFailed(exception: FirebaseException) {
            executeTaskWhenVerificationFailed()
        }

        override fun onCodeSent(verification: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
            executeTaskWhenCodeSent()
        }

        override fun onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(p0: String) {
            super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(p0)

            executeTaskWhenARequestTimedOut()
        }
    }
```

I want something like :

```
override fun onDestroy() { 
    super.onDestroy()

    cancelOngoingOTPRequest()
}
```

Is there anyway to handle this problem ? Let me know if there's anything unclear.

Comment: Do you got any hack for this