# How to stop an ongoing phone authentication request with Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have added to my phone authentication to my sign up process, in a send code activity - which sends the sms code to confirm the phone authentication process. Then, I have also added a "go-back"/"return" button which moves the user back to the main activity.

If I make the following request which sends the user a sms code to his phone:

```
PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
```

I won't be able to make another request before the defined timeout duration ends. Therefore, I thought about the easy and not messy approach, that would be to cancel the ongoing request, but unfortunately couldn't find how to do so, if even possible nowadays. I have also saw the unanswered post here: [Android Firebase OTP auth: Is there a way to cancel OTP code request programatically before the actual timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333570/android-firebase-otp-auth-is-there-a-way-to-cancel-otp-code-request-programatic)

Couldn't work with this, even though it's what I am looking for, but it has no related answers.

- Note: I am programming my project with Java and not Kotlin.

---

I have also thought about the second approach, which is to save current activity's phone number and then extract it with onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState, then resend a code sms again. But of course, it's much more complicated and messier.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to cancel an ongoing verification request by calling the `verifyPhoneNumber` method again with the same phone number, but with the `forceResendingToken` parameter set to null. This will cancel the previous request and allow to start a new one.

It is also possible to use the `PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance()` method to get a reference to the PhoneAuthProvider instance, and then call the `verifyPhoneNumber` method on that instance instead of calling it directly. This allows to call the `verifyPhoneNumber` method multiple times without canceling the previous request.

Timeout duration for verification requests is typically around 5 minutes, so if you want to allow the user to request a new code before the timeout expires, provide a way for them to do so, such as by adding a "Resend code" button to the app.

Overall, it's best to design apps in a way that minimizes the need for canceling ongoing verification requests, as this can lead to a confusing user experience. Instead, focus on providing clear instructions and options for the user, and consider using the getInstance method to avoid having to cancel requests altogether.

Comment: I see what you are talking about. What if for example, I will remove this go back button, then a user accidentally exit the app completely, how can I know that he is still in the phone authentication process?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0` where `PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance()` is deprecated and cannot set `setForceResendingToken(null)`.

When I was checking the source definition for `ForceResendingToken` I found a public method `zza()` returning new `ForceResendingToken` instance. So I tried using it `setForceResendingToken(PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken.zza())` and it worked like a charm.

Currently I'm using this when I don't have a valid `PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken` object.

I'm not sure this is the right way but it gets the job done without any issues for now.

Comment: Thanks, for more info https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthOptions.Builder#setForceResendingToken(com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken)